# Prolog Help - Cant Understand a Rule

Tags: database, prolog, rules

I have a database full of facts such as:

```
overground( watfordjunction   , watfordhighstreet , 2 ).
overground( watfordhighstreet , bushey            , 3 ).
overground( bushey            , carpenderspark    , 3 ).
overground( carpenderspark    , hatchend          , 2 ).
```

example: watford junction to watfordhighstreet takes 2 minutes.

I then designed a rule so that I can test if a journey from any station to another can be done including any reverse journeys.

```
isjourney( Station1 , Station2 ) :-
  overground( Station1 , _        , _ ) ,
  overground( _        , Station2 , _ ) ; 
  overground( Station2 , _        , _ ) ,
  overground( _        , Station1 , _ )
  .
isjourney( Station1 , Station2 ) :-
  overground( Station1 , Station3 , _ ) ,
  isjourney(  Station3 , Station2 )
  .
isjourney( Station1 , Station2 ) :-
  overground( Station4 , Station2 , _ ) ,
  isjourney(  Station1 , Station4 )
  .
```

(Excuse the underscores, I was having trouble pasting them)

In the end I came up with that which works fine, however I only managed to come up with it after trial and error so I can't explain how it works or even what its doing... Could anyone experienced with prolog explain to me what it does?

Comment: Sorry, all the facts I mentioned on the top were meant to be called overground not station, thats what happens when you have like 5 versions of the same file xD. Anyway I made the edits, hopefully things make sense now, overground is defined in the facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're taking the same class that @DavidGregg is taking. My answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789021/basic-prolog-but-struggling/8794162#8794162 might help you.

FWIW, the prolog variable `_` is the anonymous/"*don't care*" variable. A variable named something like `____` is **not** anonymous/"*don't care*". The anonymous variable unifies with anything and the unification doesn't carry over, so given facts like:

```
number(1).
letter(a).
```

a predicate such as

```
foo :- number(_) , letter(_).
```

will succeed, whereas

```
foo :- number(____) , letter(____) .
```

won't.

In your first clause

```
isjourney( Station1 , Station2 ) :-
  overground( Station1 , _        , _ ) ,
  overground( _        , Station2 , _ ) ; 
  overground( Station2 , _        , _ ) ,
  overground( _        , Station1 , _ )
  .
```

Are you sure it binds the way you think it binds?

Just like the grammars of procedural languages, prolog's AND and OR operators differ in precedence. If you're going to use the OR opeator `;`, you should parenthesize things to make the intended binding clear. Better though, IMHO, is to avoid it altogether:

```
isjourney( Station1 , Station2 ) :-
  overground( Station1 , _        , _ ) ,
  overground( _        , Station2 , _ )
  .
isjourney( Station1 , Station2 ) :- 
  overground( Station2 , _        , _ ) ,
  overground( _        , Station1 , _ )
  .
```

Your basic thought is correct, though: A route between two stations A and B exists **if**

- station A exists, and
- station B exists, and
- a direct route exists between station A and some intermediate station X, and
- a route exists between that intermediate station X and station B

I believe you've left out one case, though: where station A and station B are directly adjacent.

I would note, however, that the explicit check for a station's existence isn't really necessary: the predicate cannot succeed if a station doesn't exist.

I'd be inclined to write the predicate something like

```
isjourney(A,B) :-
  station_exists(A) ,   % verify that station A exists
  station_exists(B) ,   % verify that station B exists
  (
    route_exists(A,B)   % verify that a route exists between A and B
    ;                   % in either direction
    route_exists(B,A)
  )
  .

route_exists(A,B) :- % 1st, check for directly adjacent stations
  overground(A,B,_) ,
  .
route_exists(A,B) :- % 2nd, check for indirect routes
  overground(A,T,_) ,
  route_exists(T,B)
  .

% =========================================================
% check for the existence of a station
% we want the cut to alternatives. A station exists or it doesn't
% we don't want backtracking to succeed by finding every instance
% of the station
% in the route map.
% =========================================================
station_exists(X) :- overground(X,_,_) , ! .
station_exists(X) :- overground(_,X,_) , ! .
```

Backtracking, of course, should enumerate all possible routes in both directions.

As noted in my answer linked to above, the solution is still vulnerable to bottomless recursion if a cycle exists in the graph (if, for instance, station A links to station B, with station B linking to both stations C and A). Detection of such cycles is left to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your first clause is wrong. 
It should be

```
isjourney(Station1, Station2):- 
  overground(Station1, Station2, _).
```

The other clauses seem ok, however you could put them in one clause:

```
isjourney(Station1,Station2):-
    (overground(Station1,Station3,_), isjourney(Station3,Station2)) ; 
    (overground(Station3,Station2,_), isjourney(Station1,Station3)) .
```

Basically what you are saying is that there is a journey either if overground Station1 and Station2 succeeds or if there is an intermediate station (Station3) for which you can do a journey from Station1 to Station3 and then from Station3 to Station2 (or the reverse journey).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to answer the same thing as [the person in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789021/basic-prolog-but-struggling).

First of all, you should use your question 2 answer :

Base case, if there's directly a journey :

```
is_journey(Station1, Station2) :-
    q2(Station1, Station2).
```

Not base case, you have to use an intermediate :

```
is_journey(Station1, Station2) :-
    q2(Station1, StationTemp),
    is_journey(StationTemp, Station2).
```

Now, that won't handle cycles : you'll likely fall into infinite loops, so to handle them, you should go with :

First we call a predicate that'll call the same predicate but with 3 arguments (the last one keeps track of the stations used) :

```
is_journey(Station1, Station2) :-
    is_journey(Station1, Station2, [Station1]).
```

Then we use the same base case :

```
is_journey(Station1, Station2, _) :-
    q2(Station1, Station2).
```

Then we use almost the same recursive case, but we check for membership in `Visited` and we update `Visited` when going on with the recursion :

```
is_journey(Station1, Station2, Visited) :-
    q2(Station1, StationTemp),
    \+ member(StationTemp, Visited),
    is_journey(StationTemp, Station2, [StationTemp|Visited]).
```

BTW I don't think your OP predicate is correct since it only checks if both stations are really stations and not if both are directly connected.